# Solving for coefficients in half sum of two exponential functions

Tags: graphing-functions, exponential-sum

Let $$G(x) = \frac{\exp(-ax) + \exp(-bx)}{2}$$

I need to find the coefficients $a$ and $b$.

Given: A table of 10 values of x and their corresponding G(x) values.

I need some help in figuring out how to go about the sum.

PS: The actual problem is pertaining to Dynamic Light Scattering.

Comment: Since you have only two degrees of freedom $a,b$ to work with, and you also have 10 points on the curve, you need a version of a regression formula to do this, and the resulting $a,b$ will only be approximations of their (unknown) true values.

Answer (score 0):

As coffeemath commented, this is a typical nonlinear regression; it does not make any problem except that, in general, you need to provide reasonable estimates for parameters $a$ and $b$.

If you do not have any idea about these, what you could do is to build a regular grid over the parameters and compute for each pair the value of $$SSQ(a,b)=\sum_{i=1}^{10} \Big(\frac{e^{-ax_i} + e^{-bx_i}}{2}-G(x_i)\Big)^2$$ and look for the minimum value of this function; the best point will correspond to the starting values to use. All of this preliminary step can be done using Excel.

Now, use a nonlinear regression tool. If you do not have any, continue with a more and more refined grid procedure.

Comment: Thanks. I am however not sure if we are expected to use non linear regression. However, I was wondering if the problem can be made simpler by using series expansions of e^(-ax) and e^(-bx). This way the problem gets reduced to an algebraic expression.

Comment: No, you cannot do that. In any manner, if you look at series expansions of $e^{-ax}$ and $e^{-bx}$, the problem will still exist since multiple powers of $a$ and $b$ would appear making the problem nonlinear again. Can you try my simple idea with Excel ?

Comment: Could you please expand on which tool to use in Excel? I haven't done this type of problem before.

Comment: Give a value to $a$ and a value to $b$; for this couple, compute $SSQ(a,b)$. Change values until you find a minimum. I suppose that you can automate the generation of the grid an generate the table. Search for the minimum value.